# How to run multiple scripts in remote machine

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ssh, remote-access

I have to remotely connect to a gateway (working on Linux platform), inside which I have couple of executable files (`signingModule.sh` and `taxModule.sh`).
Now I want to write one script in my desktop which will connect to that gateway and run `signingModule.sh` and `taxModule.sh` in two different terminals.

I have written below code:

```
ssh root@10.138.77.150 #to connect to gateway
sleep 5
cd /opt/swfiscal/signingModule #path of both modules
./signingModule #executable
```

but through this code I am able to connect my gateway but after connecting to gateway nothing is happening.

2nd code:

```
source configPath # file where i have given path of both the modules(configPath is placed in local machine)
cd $FCM_SCRIPTS # variable in which i have stored the path of modules
ssh root@10.138.77.150 'sh -' < signingModule #to connect and run one module (signingModule is placed in remote machine)
```

As an output of this I am getting: `source: configPath: file not found`

Please help me working this out. Thanks in advance.

Note:

1. I can copy paste my files in that gateway if required.
2. **Gnome-Terminal** or any other alternatives of this is not working in my gateway.
3. I have to run all modules (signing and tax) in different terminal coz my other application will work only when these two modules are up. so to make them run simultaneously we have to run them in different tab or terminal.
4. I have to write a script in my local machine which will run both modules (signing and tax) which are placed in remote gateway. So i want to run that script in my local machine which is gonna hit gateway's modules.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. Is `configPath` in the local or the remote machine? Is it in the directory you run the script from? Where is `startSigningModule`? Local or remote? We need to know what has to run on the local machine and what has to run in the remote in order to help you.

Comment: yes it is in the directory i am running the scripts from. Please let me know now if it is clear.
I have two modules (signing and tax) in remote. which i have to run from local. so i have kept the path of modules (placed in remote) in configPath file. configPath file is present in local.

Comment: not really. Please edit your question and explain clearly what files are in what machine and which commands are supposed to run on local and which on the remote. Also, why in different terminals?

Comment: I hope this will work. let me know if you want some more input

Answer (score 1):

The error you got means that file `configPath` doesn't exists in folder where you did the command `source configPath`.

Assuming that:

- file `configPath` contains the statements:

  > ```
  > #!/bin/bash
  > export FCM_SCRIPTS=/path/on/remote/machine
  > ```
- In `/path/on/remote/machine` folder is present an executable file `signingModule`
- file `configPath` is located in `/path/on/local/machine` folder

If these assumptions are true, you should create on local machine a simple script `/path/on/local/machine/remoteExecution.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $FCM_SCRIPTS
./signingModule
```

and try:

```
cd /path/on/local/machine 
ssh root@10.138.77.150 'bash -s' < <(cat configPath remoteExecution.sh)
```

where `-s` option means that commands are read from the standard input.